# Struts2: Changing the starting iterator value

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, iterator

I am creating a menu and for each menu component, I have a specific id:

```
<li id="ll1"><a href="javascript:{}" id="al1">Component</a></li>
```

Retrieving the components from the DB, I used the iterator tag to display them dynamically:

```
<s:iterator value="#session.loggedinUser.compNames" status="statusObject" var="parent">
 <s:if test="#session.loggedinUser.compAccess[#statusObject.index] == 0">
  <li id="ll<s:property value="#statusObject.index"/>">
   <a href="javascript:{}" id="al<s:property value="#statusObject.index"/>" onclick="menuBar('none')">
   <s:property value="#parent"/>
   </a>
  </li>
</s:if>
```

The iterator works as I want it to and the menu list is generated perfectly. However, it starts at List id = 0, as such:

```
<li id="ll0"><a href="javascript:{}" id="al0" onclick="menuBar('Component')">Component</a>
```

Is there any way to start list id assignation at 1 while keeping the initial reading index of my iterator list at 0? (I don't want to lose the first value in my list!)

If I have confused you anywhere, please ask for clarification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean `<s:property value="#statusObject.index + 1"/>` instead of `<s:property value="#statusObject.index"/>` If this is the case... you might want to give http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html a quick scan.  Struts2 uses OGNL as the EL, usually... If you want the list to come back differently then you'll need to use JS to modify the parameters before you submit.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! I wasn't aware you could simply add a +1. I though doing that would throw off the entire thing. I wish I had more votes to give you because you just saved me from trying back-ended roundabout solutions. Thanks again!

Comment: Some things to note: use an objects methods as you would in java, you can even directly access static members(requires a struts2 configuration change). Create a new object and then do something with it, and a lot of good things. What you can't do, afaik is iterate over a POJO properties (Well you can if it provides one of the interfaces you would expect to supply iteration...).  So the subject of today is to create a tag which will create a list of Strings of such properties such that you can then use that list in an iterator all from the view.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid unnecessary calculations.

```
    <s:property value="#statusObject.count"/> index is 0-based.
    <s:property value="#statusObject.index"/> count is 1-based.
```